Why does an asynchronous FastAPI have synchronous code in authorization?
Hellow everbody)
Why does authorization have a synchronous library for creating and checking passwords?
Here's the code from the documentation:
def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

def authenticate_user(fake_db, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(fake_db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user

@app.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()],
) -> Token:
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer")


Calling this function(authenticate_user) is synchronous. In an asynchronous endpoint. Therefore, the event loop will block and the loop will not be able to transfer control to another task.
In this regard, I have several questions:

Is this library used because there is no asynchronous analogue?
How much impact will loop blocking have on the performance of the application?
How acceptable is it to use both synchronous and asynchronous code in place? What will be the disadvantages? Can this be done or should it be avoided?


What feature in passlib do you believe is dependent on IO and wouldn't return as fast as possible? async is a way to write cooperative code that says "I'm waiting for someone to return to me, so do something else in the meantime". There is no-one to wait for when calling passlib. So 1) No, it doesn't make sense to make this code async compatible 2) None 3) Not all code can be asynchronous. async is a way to scale code that is io bound in a cooperative way.


Is this library used because there is no asynchronous analogue?

I don't know whether the async analogue exists or not. But I would disagree with @MatsLindh that id doesn't make sense. If this operation is heavy and requires long time, then it would be better to insert some await asyncio.sleep(0) to let the interpreter switch to other tasks and avoid blocking event loop for long time.

How much impact will loop blocking have on the performance of the application?

Depends on the selected algorithm. But I don't think it will have strong impact.

How acceptable is it to use both synchronous and asynchronous code in
place? What will be the disadvantages? Can this be done or should it
be avoided?

If this synchronous function doesn't have any IO-bound operations and it's not very 'heavy', then it's Ok. Disadvantage is that all other tasks are frozen while your synchronous code inside async coroutine is executed. But, as I said, it's not a big problem if this function is not very heavy.
If you use heavy algorithm to hash passwords and want to avoid these blockings you can run this sync function in the threadpool (i didn't run this code, but it should work):
#from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool

password_verified = await run_in_threadpool(verify_password, password, user.hashed_password)

But remember, that executing code in the threadpool has some overheads. So, you should do this only if this call really has impact to your app performance.
